# Can authority know the type of a rejected visa?

Tags: working-visas, france, schengen

I am going to apply for a work visa in France. I have two rejections from Malta embassy, "there are reasonable doubts as to the reliability of the statements made as regards please specify".
The purpose of my application is work. I was not shocked. I believe it is my fault for providing contradictory information beside telling consular officers that my employer is whom paid for my work permit and which is untrue. Also, it may be they called my employer in my country to check if I work with him or I had a fake work certificate. Which, my employer refused to give it to me at that time, and I have submitted old one.

Anyway, I am anxious about my next application in France. My question is can consular officers know certain details about my previous one and the type of the visa I had applied for. I know that too sometimes authorities reject no matter the type of a visa in a arbitrary manner.

Thank you
Note: I haven't received a notification for banning in my refusal letter

Comment: "*...telling consular officers that my employer is whom paid for my work permit and which is untrue.*" This is unfortunate because that is not alone at all a reason for a visa rejection. It does raise an eyebrow and perhaps a warning flag in some cases, but there are valid reasons why the employee might pay for their permit application (even if that payment is done through an agency), depending a variety of circumstances. The deception however, is a crushing blow to your credibility with the visa departmént.

Answer (score 1):

> Can authority know the type of a rejected visa?

Yes, absolutely, all visa refusals are kept for a maximum of 5 years in the [Visa Information System](https://www.eulisa.europa.eu/Activities/Large-Scale-It-Systems/Vis)

Extracts from the [REGULATION (EC) No 767/2008](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32008R0767)

Article 4 :

> > 1. ‘visa’ means:
>
> - **(e) ‘national long-stay visa valid concurrently as a short-stay visa’ as defined in Article 18 of the Schengen Convention;**

Article 12 :

> > For the purposes of this Regulation, the following definitions shall apply:
>
> 1. Where a decision has been taken to refuse a visa, the visa authority which refused the visa shall add the following data to the
>    application file:
>
> (a) status information indicating that the visa has been refused;
>
> (b) the authority that refused the visa, including its location;
>
> (c) place and date of the decision to refuse the visa.
>
> 2. The application file shall also indicate the **ground(s) for refusal** of the visa, which shall be one or more of the following. The
>    applicant:
>
> (c) does not justify the purpose and conditions of stay, in particular
> is considered to represent a specific risk of illegal immigration
> pursuant to Part V of the Common Consular Instructions;

Article 15 :

> 1. The competent visa authority shall consult the VIS for the purposes of the examination of applications and the decisions relating to those applications, including the decision whether to annul, revoke, extend or shorten the validity of the visa in accordance with the relevant provisions.

Comment: I want to know if every single application will be erased automatically after five years counting the day I have applied? by the mean if I decide to apply again it will not add timeframe to the first application?  Also do I still have a little chance to get a work visa or I am awasting my time? Thank you sir

Comment: You lied to the consular officer about who paid for your work permit and you submitted an old work certificate which may well have been checked and discovered. IMHO you’re wasting your time and money.

Comment: @Traveller Some respect please! We are not in court . I made huge mistake but I am not criminal. Also I have mentioned previously that I was "Under stress" during the interview, an agency told me that I should told the embassy staff that my application for work is online (LinkedIn..) Whatever. However I have told the consulate that the later was via agency but I did not made payment because its strictly unlawful in my COUNTRY. Also I am seeking for a practical solution to diffuse the situation not hearing some offensive comment.

Comment: @Ahmed2024 I gave my objective opinion of your situation. No part of my comment uses offensive language, it merely states the truth based on what is written in your question.

Comment: "*...but I am not criminal.*" Nobody is saying anybody is criminal, and being rejected for a visa does not imply such. "*...but I did not made payment because its strictly unlawful in my COUNTRY.*" I'd be surprised, but interested, at this being true. Normally it's the country to whom the application is being made that would care about payment origin. The home country could care less I would think. "*I am seeking for a practical solution to diffuse the situation*". Worst case, your application to France is rejected. Everybody moves on. I don't see a ban here, but maybe others  know better.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Do you have any idea if the nature of visa purpose can have a different impact? For example if I will apply for a PhD or a Master degree, will it improve my chance regarding my VIS history?